# dynamically change column in oracle cursor

Tags: plsql

I have 50 columns in one table and need to update each column.
Trying the below plsql code. (commented update section is working).

But dynamically generated column is not accepting.
(PL/SQL: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification)
 Anybody can help please?

```
DECLARE
cursor udas is
select 5109 as udaid from dual
union all    
select 8209 as udaid from dual;           
BEGIN
for uda in udas loop
DECLARE
cursor c1 is
select 
x.item, x.uda_id, x.uda_value, x.uda_value_desc 
from 
hp2_uda_data x 
where 
x.uda_type='LOV'
and x.uda_id=uda.udaid;
begin    
for i in c1 loop
begin
/*update testtable set item_uda_5109_v=i.uda_value, 
item_uda_5109_d=i.uda_value_desc where item_code=i.item;*/
update testtable set 'item_uda_'||uda.udaid||'_v'=i.uda_value, 
'item_uda_'||uda.udaid||'_d'=i.uda_value_desc where item_code=i.item;
end;
end loop;
commit;
end;
end loop;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic code requires `execute immediate`:

```
execute immediate
'update testtable
 set    item_uda_'||uda.udaid||'_v = :b1
      , item_uda_'||uda.udaid||'_d = :b2
 where  item_code = :b3'
using i.uda_value, i.uda_value_desc, i.item;
```

It can be useful to construct the dynamic code in a variable so that you can report or log it in the event of failure.

I also recommend looking into [code indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) as a useful technique for making code readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really helpful.

Comment: Glad it helped, but "thank you" comments are discouraged on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers